# GetRequestStream() timeout exception

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, httprequest, webclient

I would like to make a simple Http request using the Webclient:

```
public string PostRequest(object json, string contentType, string server)
{
    try
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(server);
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Timeout = 10000;
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
        }


        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

The problem is that the request.GetRequestStream() part does never return and will always timeout (with the default 100s and the 10s as well).  I am using a samsung xcover 4 with android 7 and later android 8.1. the server string works perfectly when copyed into my standard browser on the PC.On the device browser itself it does not work (timeout). The contentType is "application/json".

Is there something I can do to fix this problem or is there another method to send httprequests in xamarin that are not broken?

the server itself is working and I can ping it form my device:

```
public int PingHost(string nameOrAddress)
{
    int pingCount = 0;
    Ping pinger = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            pinger = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
            pingCount += reply.Status == IPStatus.Success ? 1:0;
        }
        catch (Exception){ pingCount = - 1; }
        finally
        {
            pinger?.Dispose();
        }
        if (pingCount == -1) return -1;

    }
    return pingCount;
}
```

thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you test your code from your pc, or just the url form the browser, does it need credentials, are you sure you passing in the right url.

Comment: I tested it now and it works just fine although it is the same machine as the server. But the url call works for the pc of a coworker aswell.

Comment: Does the url work from the phone browser?

Comment: no I get the same timeout error (I have edited the post to make that more clear). I tested the code on a different pc and It did work. But is was really slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have a working code in my application and it is something like this:

```
 public HttpClient apiClient;
```

**GetType API**

```
 public async Task<string> GetServiceData(string srvUrl)
    {
        try
        {
          apiClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler(throwOnCaptiveNetwork: false, customSSLVerification: false)); // SSL true if you have custom SLL in your API 
          apiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_yourbaseUrl); // Url where the service is hosted
          apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("",""); //defualt req header key value in case any
          var respon = await apiClient.GetAsync(srvUrl).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // svrUrl is the name of the api that you want to consume 
          if (respon != string.Empty)
          {
               return respon;
          }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException reqEx)
        {
           return string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

**PostType API**

```
  public async Task<string> PostServiceData(string srvUrl, object srvModel)
    {
        try
        {
          var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(srvModel);//your parameter to the API
          var stringContent = new StringContent(myContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
          apiClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler(throwOnCaptiveNetwork: false, customSSLVerification: true));// SSL true if you have custom SLL in your API
          apiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_yourbaseUrl); // Url where the service is hosted
          apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("",""); //defualt req header key value in case any
          apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
               .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));//ACCEPT header
            var respon = await apiClient.PostAsync(srvUrl, stringContent);
                var resReslt = respon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return resReslt;
            }
            else
                return string.Empty;

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException reqEx)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Good luck In case of queries revert!